# Weka dynamic sentence classification

Tags: classification, weka, categorization, sentence

Could you please give me some hints whether (and how) I can do this in WEKA?

I have lots of sentences and then I receive a new one which has to be categorized.

The existing categories come into being on the basis of existing sentences. Firstly, how to create those categories?

Then, when the new sentence comes, how do I categorize it into one of those previously created categories (not a new one).

Comment: We need more information to answer this.  What do you want to base the categorization on?  One of the hardest parts of any machine learning project is deciding on what features you are going to use to do the categorization.

Comment: I believe we can calculate some similarity (distance) between two sentences - if it is too big (they do not have enough words in commom) then create new category for the second sentence. Right?